# Is there science backing the claim that walking barefoot is healthier than walking with shoes?

Tags: medical-myths, posture, walking, footwear, barefoot

I keep hearing about the benefits of walking barefoot.

One benefit I hear is that walking barefoot "[allows] us to synchronize with the earth’s natural electric charge" ([source](https://www.mindbodygreen.com/0-9099/the-surprising-health-benefits-of-going-barefoot.html)). This sounds like BS to me, but I wouldn't know any better.

The other benefit has to do with improving posture. I think the argument is that a lot of people's shoes are not tailored to their feet, and this can lead to posture problems down the line.

Is there scientific evidence backing this claim?

Comment: I think this falls under the general heading of a non-falsifiable claim. They make claim x and then say it must be true since there is no scientific evidence that it is not. And though you ask, "Is there scientific evidence backing this claim?" what you're really asking is there any scientific evidence that it is not.

Comment: @BillDOe The specific "natural electric charge" argument the OP references is clearly BS, but the general question of "is walking barefoot (better in some way or in some context) better than walking with shoes" is certainly a scientifically studied question.

Comment: @BryanKrause, you're correct. I was referring to the second paragraph. I should have made that clear in my comment.

Comment: @pushkin your question relates to "walking", do you want evidence supporting barefoot running as well?

Comment: @faustus Nah, I'm not as interested in that

Comment: [The Wikipedia article](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barefoot) seems like a good starting point.

Comment: A cardiologist, Stephen Sinatra, MD, and some others have published studies on the emf/voltage aspect of walking barefoot. See NCBI on pubmed and his website. Sinatra has also written a book on the subject. A Harvard anthropologist and Nike, the shoe company, have both done substantial research in the postural and exercise advantages of moving barefoot. My roommate from college, who typically goes barefoot and has run marathons barefoot participated in the Harvard study. I believe Nike's research was separate, but may have hired the Harvard prof as a consultant.

Comment: @JonathanCender - I am not sure how much credance can be given to the research due to the fact that there is the disclaimer *"G. Chevalier, S. T. Sinatra, and J. L. Oschman are independent contractors for Earthx L. Inc., the company sponsoring earthing research, and own a small percentage of shares in the company."* ([Chevalier, et al. 2013](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3576907) and [2012](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3265077)).

Comment: @Chris Rogers Good point. They are not truly independent researchers. I hope independent researchers interest themselves in the topic. Sinatra, at least, became interested after doing some research, but before having shares. I do not know if that research was published. But he saw enough in the research to put skin in the game.